# Unregistered domain heiiehdsx.com in my referrer logs

Tags: referrer, http-referer, referer, referrals, referrer-spam

Lately, the unregistered (available) domain heiiehdsx.com has been showing up in my HTTP referrer logs.  It comes from a variety of IP addresses (none very similar).  When I Google the domain, the only results are reports of it appearing in other server logs as well.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [spoofed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack) header.

Most HTTP headers can be very easily [spoofed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack).

FireFox even has an [add-in for modifying headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967/).

Chances these are from a bot/spammer that is looking for vulnerable targets.

Answer (score 0):

This is [referer spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam). Bad guys trying to provoke you to visit their websites.

Comment: Not just bad guys.. there are some nice plugins for browsers that fetch a list of 'referrers' to send with your requests. That is a lot more fun (for people who just *hate* trackers and *love to mess with them*), especially if those links contain viruses.. that should teach them tracking kiddies not to visit (and hopefully subsequently quit) tracking their visitors.